# cannot find Signcert hyperledger fabric

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric-ca

i am trying to run the fabric network and getting the following error.

```
peer1.org2.example.com | 2019-08-09 19:37:30.561 UTC [main] InitCmd -> 
ERRO 001 Cannot run peer because error when setting up MSP of type bccsp 
from directory /etc/hyperledger/fabric/msp: could not load a valid signer certificate 
from directory /etc/hyperledger/fabric/msp/signcerts: stat /etc/hyperledger/fabric/msp/signcerts: 
no such file or directory
```

I also tried to find the directory in the crypto-config folder and don't see signcerts folder there as well. I am not sure if

`cryptogen generate --config=./crypto-config.yaml`

generates this folder or not.

I am using docker-compose to run the fabric network. and I have following two mounts

```
    ../crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/msp:/etc/hyperledger/fabric/msp
    ../crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/tls:/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls
```

Please suggest.

Comment: `cryptogen generate --config=./crypto-config.yaml` should generate a directory `crypto-config`.. are you seeing that dir?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the issue was, the folder it generates is inside the

```
crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/msp/signcert
```

and i was looking in the

```
crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/msp
```

also one mount was wrong. Another things with orderer was relative mapping `./ instead of ../`

Thanks for your help @adarshJha

Answer (score 2):

cryptogen generates the crypto-config directory but to avoid your error. you should run following commands by making changes according to your system path.

docker exec -it cli bash

```
CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp
CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer0.org1.example.com:7051
CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID="Org1MSP"
CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/tls/ca.crt
```